# How to create a new column presenting top 5 rows and remaining rows clubbed as miscellaneous?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

A newbie to python. I have a dataset in which column 'car' has 87 distinct values. I want to change the column to present top 10 car brands in the column and remaining 77 will be clubbed as Miscellaneous. Sample demo below:

```
In[]:  car_sales['car'].unique()

Out[]: array(['Ford', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'Nissan', 'Honda', 'Renault', 'BMW',
   'Land Rover', 'Volkswagen', 'Audi', 'Chrysler', 'Jaguar',
   'Mitsubishi', 'Kia', 'Porsche', 'Toyota', 'Hyundai'], dtype=object)
```

I was trying to club  all other as a dictionary first except top 5

```
my dict = {'Miscellaneous' :  'Nissan', 'Honda', 'Renault', 'BMW',
   'Land Rover', 'Volkswagen', 'Audi', 'Chrysler', 'Jaguar'}
```

Ho do I go ahead now to see my column car as below:

**car**

Ford

Mercedes-Benz

Nissan

Audi

Jaguar

*Miscellaneous*

Looking for assistance. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) to handle these types of problems. `categorical` type also has the added benefit of being more memory efficient.

#### Example:

```
cars = ['Ford', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'Nissan', 'Honda', 'Renault', 'BMW',
        'Land Rover', 'Volkswagen', 'Audi', 'Chrysler', 'Jaguar',
        'Mitsubishi', 'Kia', 'Porsche', 'Toyota', 'Hyundai']

df = pd.DataFrame({'cars': np.random.choice(cars, 100)})

top_5 = ['Ford', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'Nissan', 'Audi', 'Jaguar', 'Miscellaneous']

df['cars_refined'] = pd.Categorical(df['cars'], categories=top_5).fillna('Miscellaneous')

print(df.head(10))

            cars   cars_refined
0  Mercedes-Benz  Mercedes-Benz
1  Mercedes-Benz  Mercedes-Benz
2     Volkswagen  Miscellaneous
3           Ford           Ford
4     Mitsubishi  Miscellaneous
5         Toyota  Miscellaneous
6        Porsche  Miscellaneous
7          Honda  Miscellaneous
8            Kia  Miscellaneous
9         Jaguar         Jaguar
```

Comment: nice one Chris :) +1

Comment: Hi Chris, It works fine. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure I understand what you're doing but I guess you can do something like this:

```
[x for x in car_sales['car'] if x not in my_dict['Miscellaneous']] + ['Miscellaneous']
```

provided that `my_dict` is defined as follows (notice that the value in the dict is a set):

```
my_dict = {'Miscellaneous': {'Nissan', 'Honda', 'Renault', 'BMW', 'Land Rover', 'Volkswagen', 'Audi', 'Chrysler', 'Jaguar'}}
```

So you can have something like (I assume you're using numpy and want the result as a numpy array):

```
new_array = np.array([x for x in car_sales['car'] if x not in my_dict['misc']] + ['Miscellaneous'])
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am using pandas so above answer will help.